# module 'torch.jit' has no attribute 'unused'

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, fpga, torchvision

I am a student trying to get my hands into facial recognition using Ultra96 and I am having troubles running my program.

I have tried to install nightly version into my Ultra96 however, it does not solve my problem. The current OS is pynq 2.6 which is Linux and it is using jupyter notebook to run the codes.

Please offer me some guidance!

Answer (score 0):

use `torchvision 0.4.0`:

```
pip uninstall torchvision
pip install torchvision==0.4.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

This will work for sure
EDIT : if above cmd wont work , use this `pip install torchvision==0.4.0`

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the response. 
Unfortunately, I can not find the required version using the command you've sent above.

Comment: try with this alone `pip install torchvision==0.4.0`